# How to open file in Libre Office and save this like .doc file?

Tags: python, libreoffice

How to open file in Libre Office and save this like .doc file? It is possible? (create script for this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [`libreoffice` manual](http://manned.org/libreoffice.1) (as a command line utility) you don't need python for this, but `libreoffice` should directly support this:

> **--convert-to** output_file_extension[:output_filter_name] [--outdir output_dir] file... Batch  converts  files. If --outdir is not
>   specified then the current working directory is used as the output
>   directory for the convertedfiles.
>
> Examples:
>
> **--convert-to** pdf *.doc
>
> Converts all .doc files to PDFs.
>
> **--convert-to** pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir /home/user *.doc
>
> Converts all .doc files to PDFs using the settings in the Writer PDF
>   export dialog and saving them in /home/user.

Id you need to process many files, you could write simple bash script like this:

```bash
for i in `find folder -type f -name *.lwp` ; do
    libreoffice --headless --convert-to doc:"MS Word 2003 XML" $i
done
```

More detail instructions on how to invoke this command [here](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/) or in manual specified earlier.

And you can basically do the same invocation from python and [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/subprocess.html):

```python
import os
import os.path
import subprocess

for i in os.listdir( SOURCE_FOLDER):
    if not i.endswith( '.lwp'):
        continue

    path = os.path.join( SOURCE_FOLDER, i)
    args = ['libreoffice', '--headless', '--convert-to',
            'doc:"MS Word 2003 XML"', path]

    subprocess.call(args, shell=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

On win7, using LO 4.1 I had to do the following (from command line, you probably need to convert  `%f` to `%%f` if running in a cmd script):

```
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program
for %f in (*.odt) do (
    soffice.exe --headless --convert-to doc --outdir "C:\tmp" %f
)
```

Notes:

- it will NOT work if any instance of LO is open!
- outdir IS required
- wildcards for input files are NOT supported (hence the for loop)

An according python script could look like this:

```
import os
import subprocess as sp

lo = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\soffice.exe'

args = '--headless --convert-to doc --outdir "%(out)s" "%(inp)s"'

inp_path = './odt'
out_path = './doc'

inp_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.abspath(inp_path))
out_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.abspath(out_path))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inp_path):
  for fname in files:
    if fname.endswith('.odt'):
      i = os.path.join(inp_path,fname)
      sp.call(lo + ' ' + args%{'out': out_path, 'inp': i})
```

(copied and modified my answer from ask.libreoffice, also posted on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/207272/batch-convert-odg-to-ai-cdr-or-jpg/644864#644864))